# Okay, I'm gonna go eat this steak in the bathroom - why is it funny?

Tags: family-guy

From Family Guy - Turban Cowboy [S11E15], why is [Okay, I'm gonna go eat this steak in the bathroom](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/08b2e94f-c975-45a5-b60b-93752c9ef8b6) funny?

I imagine that I am missing a cultural refernce, but internet search does not help.

[image]

Comment: Is there something happening / said before that?

Comment: Without context first thought is "racism?"

Comment: @e2-e4 the script is [here](https://subslikescript.com/series/Family_Guy-182576/season-11/episode-15-Turban_Cowboy). I don't see anything leading up to it

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY that was my first thought too - but, not being Anerican, I don't know if this is a stereotype, or even how it could be

Comment: Before that scene they explitly talking about racism and "how everyone have their quirks". Naming black men changing their shirts while telling a story. It's a "joke" about racism

Comment: Aha ! Yes, I see that. I had forgotten the, as the have the bit about pie in between that and the steak. So, should I change the title from "why is this funny?" To "how is this racist?"? Or would that be too contentious (as Family Guy is)? I don't want to offend anyone by asking for an explanation.

Comment: There’s a similar joke made in the Simpson’s that seems like it can’t be related to race, “I’m going to go order a steak and eat it on the toilet”: https://yarn.co/yarn-clip/2a9eb3f5-5bec-4713-b956-63f3c0cb97fe

Comment: I think the food is simply disgusting, and "eating it in the bathroom" actually means he's going to flush the steak down the toilet.

Comment: [`citation needed`].  No matter where he eats it, some of it will end up in the toilet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's about race, at least not directly. It could be implying and related to them eating at a cheap steak house with poorly trained chefs. Apparently eating improperly cooked steak is known to cause diarrhea, so the joke could very well be related to eating a cheap steak making the person eating it have to use the toilet immediately.

If there is a racial component to the joke, it could be that there's a stereotype that the demographic in question might be likely to order steak at low quality restaurants where they are likely to cook it incorrectly. I'm not familiar with such a stereotype, but it's a possibility.

See: https://www.livestrong.com/article/473861-steak-and-diarrhea/

Note: This episode was removed from all streaming services after the Boston Marathon bombing because it contains a cutaway joke where Peter drives a van over some marathon runners to "win" the Boston Marathon. There is a transcript of the episode available, but I don't think linking to it is appropriate since it is probably not properly licensed.